# file uploading on codeigniter is not working on the server but works on localhost

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to upload the file using codeigniter to the server but that is not working for me.But the same code is working fine on the localhost. Files are uploading successfully on it.

Please check my code first

```
public function add_new_book()

    {
    echo $image = $_FILES ['bookcover']['name']; 

    $img=$_FILES ['bookcover'];

    $config['upload_path'] = 'uploads'; 

    $config['overwrite'] = 'TRUE';

    $config["allowed_types"] = 'jpg|jpeg|png|gif|pdf';

    $config["max_size"] = '140000';

    $config["max_width"] = '1400';

    $config["max_height"] = '1400';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);



    if(!$this->upload->do_upload('bookfile')) 

    {               
        echo "error file";

        $this->data['error'] = $this->upload->display_errors(); 

        echo json_encode(array("result"=>$this->data['error']));

        exit;

    } 



    if(!$this->upload->do_upload('bookcover')) 

    {               
        echo "error file";

        $this->data['error'] = $this->upload->display_errors(); 

        echo json_encode(array("result"=>$this->data['error']));

        exit;

    } 



    $udata['bookname'] = $this->input->post('bookname');

    $udata['author'] = $this->input->post('author');

    $udata['Description'] = $this->input->post('description'); 

    $udata['coverImage'] =  $_FILES ['bookcover']['name']; 

    $udata['book'] =  $_FILES ['bookfile']['name']; 

    $udata['createddate'] = date("Y-m-d h:i:sa");

    $udata['isavailable'] = '1';

    $res = $this->CreateBook_model->insert_books_to_db($udata); 

    echo json_encode($res);  

 }
```

The same code is working fine on localhost but getting 500 internal server error on it in console.

I have go through all the questions related to this problem on stackoverflow but nothing is working. So please donot consider it duplicate. Help is appricated

Comment: a) enable error reporting and look a the logs b) what are the specs of the servers? http-software, php-version, operating system, .... c) have you checked file permissions?

Comment: enable error reporting is not working because I am calling this function using ajax post @FranzGleichmann

Comment: error reporting *is* working, because a) you could *manually* execute the request and b) *there is a log file* which you should look at

Comment: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting function at line no 124.. @FranzGleichmann

Comment: there you've got your error. apparently, it is *not* the same code.

Comment: Try `$config['upload_path'] = './uploads';`  not `$config['upload_path'] = 'uploads'; ` Don't for get to set your folder permissions upload 0777

Comment: not working @wolfgang1983

Comment: why you wrote this code? ```echo $image = $_FILES ['bookcover']['name']; 
```

Answer (score -1):

please kindly check these on your php.ini file and make sure that you are uploading less size then they are given there:

```
max_execution_time
max_input_time
upload_max_filesize
memory_limit
```